# Save databound datagridview image to memoryStream

Tags: c#

Any example on how to save an image from a data bound datagidview control to memoryStream?

I know with PictureBox we could do

```
pictureBox1.Image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

What about a databound DataGridViewImage?

---

I'm getting error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

```
 Private Sub conv_photo()

    'converting photo to binary data 


    Dim ms As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream()
    TryCast(DataGridView1.Columns(1), DataGridViewImageColumn).Image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg)`Right here error`

    Dim photo_aray As Byte() = New Byte(CInt(ms.Length - 1)) {}
    ms.Position = 0
    ms.Read(photo_aray, 0, photo_aray.Length)
    _Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_m_barrImg", photo_aray)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You would do the exact same thing with a `DataGridViewImageColumn`, you just need to get a reference to the column e.g.

```
(dataGrid.Columns[columnIndex] as DataGridViewImageColumn).Image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that. give me a a couple of minutes